# Update Query:ERROR: XX000: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate

Tags: sql-update, amazon-redshift

I am going to start working on RedShift, so I have started making easy queries. But there is an easy query that it is not working.

This is the error that appears, and I do not understand why.

ERROR: 42P10: subquery in FROM may not refer to other relations of same query level
The query:

```
      UPDATE table1 
  SET    income = nvl ( y.income, 0 )
  FROM   (
  SELECT date , income
                FROM     table2
                where date=201810
                GROUP BY date) y
  WHERE table1.date =   y.date
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the table being update in the join. For example:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET    income = nvl( y.income, 0 )
FROM table1,
     (SELECT   "date" , income
      FROM     table2
      WHERE    "date"=201810
      GROUP BY "date") y
WHERE table1."date" =   y."date"
```